# Querying PostgreSQL for Open-High-Low-Close (OHLC) report

Tags: sql, postgresql, finance

I am trying to query a table in PostgreSQL 8.4.2 server for to get open-high-low-close data.  The table and my first query are below.

**Question:**
Is there a way to get the same results without using subqueries as in the example query below?  Perhaps using FIRST_VALUE() or LAST_VALUE() window methods?

```
-- FIRST ATTEMPT AT OHLC
SELECT
  contract_id
, TO_CHAR(ts, 'YYMMDDHH24MI')
, (SELECT price FROM fill minF WHERE minF.fill_id = MIN(f.fill_id)) AS open
, MAX(f.price) AS high
, MIN(f.price) AS low
, (SELECT price FROM fill maxF WHERE maxF.fill_id = MAX(f.fill_id)) AS close
FROM fill f
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;

-- SIMPLIFIED DDL
CREATE TABLE fill
(
    contract_id SEQUENCE PRIMARY KEY
,   ts          TIMESTAMP
,   price       NUMERIC(10,4)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to get sub-day resolution.  This appears to work well.

```
SELECT
  contract_id
, the_minute
, open
, high
, low
, close
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    contract_id
  , TO_CHAR(ts, 'YYMMDDHH24MI') AS the_minute
  , MIN(price) OVER w            AS low
  , MAX(price) OVER w            AS high
  , LAST_VALUE(price) OVER w     AS open   -- Note the window is in reverse (first value comes last)
  , FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER w    AS close  -- Note the window is in reverse (last value comes first)
  , RANK() OVER w                AS the_rank
  FROM fill
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY contract_id, TO_CHAR(ts, 'YYMMDDHH24MI') ORDER BY fill_id DESC)
) AS inr
WHERE the_rank = 1
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Thank you, Scott.  You answer helped me get to the following solution.

Comment: where the *fill_id* parameter comes from? I'm actually trying to adapt this query to my case but with no success

Answer (score 5):

You have yours grouped down to the minute. Which I'm going to assume is wrong because these are typically done by day. If I'm wrong, you'll have to change it back.

```
SELECT DISTINCT contract_id, ts::date,
  min(price) OVER w,
  max(price) OVER w,
 first_value(price) OVER w, 
 last_value(price) OVER w
FROM fill
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY contract_id, ts::date ORDER BY ts)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Scott, but I am trying to get higher resolution than 1-day intervals.  Your query helped me understand windowing a bit better and I think I have a solution.

Comment: You might want to add `rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following` at the end of the `PARTITION BY` expression or otherwise with `ORDER BY` inside the window function you might get some unexpected results. The following answer provides more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639840/partition-by-with-order-by-clause-in-postgresql

Answer (score 3):

I have found a very convenient method with the [Timescale extension](https://www.timescale.com/) for PostgresSQL. It gives the ability to group by arbitrary time intervals. The function is called `time_bucket()` and has the same syntax as the built-in `date_trunc()` function but takes an interval instead of a time precision as first parameter. No need to use windowing/partitioning. [Here](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#time_bucket) you can find its API Docs. This is an example:

```sql
SELECT  
    time_bucket('1 minute', timestamp_) timebucket,
    (array_agg(price ORDER BY timestamp_ ASC))[1] open,
    MAX(price) high,
    MIN(price) low,
    (array_agg(price ORDER BY timestamp_ DESC))[1] close,
    SUM(turnover) turnover,
    COUNT(*) nr_ticks
FROM price_tick
GROUP BY timebucket
ORDER BY timebucket
```

You may also take a look at the [continuous aggregate views](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/continuous-aggregates) if you want the *'grouped by an interval'* views be updated automatically with new ingested data and if you want to query these views on a frequent basis. This can save you a lot of resources and will make your queries a lot faster.

Comment: Just curious, what is `turnover`? Is it the 1 min volume divided by shares outstanding?

Comment: @dvtan In this case the turnover describes the monetary amount that has been traded at the particular time interval. If you buy 10 shares for the price of 50$ then your turnover is 500$. This transaction would represent one row in the database with a price and the corresponding turnover (of course you could also store only the the number of traded shares and calculate the turnover for each time interval).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
select FLOOR(MIN(ts) / :period) * :period                    as timestamp,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(MIN(CONCAT(ts, '_', price)), '_', -1) as open,
       max(price)                                            as high,
       min(price)                                            as low,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(CONCAT(ts, '_', price)), '_', -1) as close,
       sum(amount)                                           as volume
from uni_tx
where asset = :asset
  and ts between :startTime and :endTime
GROUP BY FLOOR(ts / :period)
order by timestamp
```