# Partition By with Order By Clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table with these values;

```
user_id ts                  val
uid1    19.05.2019 01:49:50  0
uid1    19.05.2019 01:50:15  0
uid1    19.05.2019 01:50:20  0
uid1    19.05.2019 01:59:50  1
uid1    19.05.2019 02:20:10  1
uid1    19.05.2019 02:20:15  0
uid1    19.05.2019 02:20:19  0
uid1    19.05.2019 02:30:53  1
uid1    19.05.2019 11:10:25  1
uid1    19.05.2019 11:13:40  0
uid1    19.05.2019 11:13:50  0
uid1    19.05.2019 11:20:19  1
uid2    19.05.2019 15:01:44  0
uid2    19.05.2019 15:05:55  0
uid2    19.05.2019 17:19:35  1
uid2    19.05.2019 17:20:01  0
uid2    19.05.2019 17:20:35  0
uid2    19.05.2019 19:15:50  1
```

When I query this table with only partition by clause, result seems like this;

Query : `select *, sum(val) over (partition by user_id) as res from example_table;`

```
user_id ts                  val res
uid1    19.05.2019 01:49:50  0  5
uid1    19.05.2019 01:50:15  0  5
uid1    19.05.2019 01:50:20  0  5
uid1    19.05.2019 01:59:50  1  5
uid1    19.05.2019 02:20:10  1  5
uid1    19.05.2019 02:20:15  0  5
uid1    19.05.2019 02:20:19  0  5
uid1    19.05.2019 02:30:53  1  5
uid1    19.05.2019 11:10:25  1  5
uid1    19.05.2019 11:13:40  0  5
uid1    19.05.2019 11:13:50  0  5
uid1    19.05.2019 11:20:19  1  5
uid2    19.05.2019 15:01:44  0  2
uid2    19.05.2019 15:05:55  0  2
uid2    19.05.2019 17:19:35  1  2
uid2    19.05.2019 17:20:01  0  2
uid2    19.05.2019 17:20:35  0  2
uid2    19.05.2019 19:15:50  1  2
```

In the above results, **res** column has total sum value of the **val** column for each partition. But, If I'll query table with partition by and order by, I'm getting these results;

Query: `select *, sum(val) over (partition by user_id order by ts) as res from example_table;`

```
user_id ts                  val res
uid1    19.05.2019 01:49:50  0  0
uid1    19.05.2019 01:50:15  0  0
uid1    19.05.2019 01:50:20  0  0
uid1    19.05.2019 01:59:50  1  1
uid1    19.05.2019 02:20:10  1  2
uid1    19.05.2019 02:20:15  0  2
uid1    19.05.2019 02:20:19  0  2
uid1    19.05.2019 02:30:53  1  3
uid1    19.05.2019 11:10:25  1  4
uid1    19.05.2019 11:13:40  0  4
uid1    19.05.2019 11:13:50  0  4
uid1    19.05.2019 11:20:19  1  5
uid2    19.05.2019 15:01:44  0  0
uid2    19.05.2019 15:05:55  0  0
uid2    19.05.2019 17:19:35  1  1
uid2    19.05.2019 17:20:01  0  1
uid2    19.05.2019 17:20:35  0  1
uid2    19.05.2019 19:15:50  1  2
```

But with order by clause, **res** column has the cumulative sum of the **value** column for each row for each partition.

Whyy? I can't understand this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update

This behavior is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

> #### 4.2.8. Window Function Calls
>
> [..]
>   The default framing option is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which is
>   the same as `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. With
>   `ORDER BY`, this sets the frame to be all rows from the partition
>   start up through the current row's last `ORDER BY` peer. Without
>   `ORDER BY`, this means all rows of the partition are included in the
>   window frame, since all rows become peers of the current row.

That means:

In absence of a *frame_clause* – `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is used by default. That includes:

- All rows "preceding" the current row according to the `ORDER BY` clause
- The current row
- All rows which have the same values in the `ORDER BY` columns as the current row

In absence of an `ORDER BY` clause – `ORDER BY NULL` is assumed (though I'm guessing again). Thus the *frame* will include all rows from the *partition*, because the values in the `ORDER BY` column(s) are the same (which is always `NULL`) in every row.

#### Original answer:

**Disclaimer:** The following is more a guess than a qualified answer. I didn't find any documentation, which can confirm what I write. At the same time I don't think that currently given answers correctly explain the behavior.

The reason for the diffrence in the results is not directly the ORDER BY clause, since `a + b + c` is the same as `c + b + a`. The reason is (and that is my guess) that the ORDER BY clause implicitly defines the **frame_clause** as

```
rows between unbounded preceding and current row
```

Try the following query:

```
select *
, sum(val) over (partition by user_id) as res
, sum(val) over (partition by user_id order by ts) as res_order_by
, sum(val) over (
    partition by user_id
    order by ts
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row
  ) as res_order_by_unbounded_preceding
, sum(val) over (
    partition by user_id
    -- order by ts
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row
  ) as res_preceding
, sum(val) over (
    partition by user_id
    -- order by ts
    rows between current row and unbounded following
  ) as res_following
, sum(val) over (
    partition by user_id
    order by ts
    rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
  ) as res_orderby_preceding_following

from example_table;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=388cb9e66922b8c36c2f27c9f10eed75)

You will see, that you can get a cumulative sum without an ORDER BY clause aswell as get a "full" sum with the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @RaymondNijland `ROW_NUMBER()` is a different beast :-) and actually doesn't really make (much) sense without `ORDER BY`. I was only talking about `SUM()` here.

Comment: i removed mine other comment on accidentally.. i also assume the PostgreSQL optimizer checks which aggregated function you use before the `OVER()` part.. as it indeed should not matter of you execute `SUM(1, 2, 3)` or `SUM(3, 2, 1)` the order does not change the result so the window function calculation can/should be consided to be deterministic ("fixed")...

Comment: Like you are saying and what i also said in mine deleted comment `ROW_NUMBER()` is out off scope of this question.. But mine comment was more meant on the general qoute you made.. As iam pretty sure that general  qoute should not work like that for `ROW_NUMBER()` as i assume the optimizer ideally requires a deterministic `ORDER BY` on `ROW_NUMBER()`... But your answer and comment is spot on so +1

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! So, assume that we use the "x" column for "order by" clause. This column may have the same for any rows. In this case, "order by" will use the all rows which have the same "x" column value at the same time. Right?

Comment: That is correct. If `x` has the same value in every row, then `ORDER BY x` has the same effect as not having the `ORDER BY` clause. You could also use any constant value like `ORDER BY 'some_constant_value'`. But again: It's not the `ORDER BY` clause alone - it's the default `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` window frame, which depends on the ORDER BY clause and "decides", which rows to include in the `SUM()`. In your case: Any row with `ts` <= `ts` of the current row.

Comment: Great! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

That is how `order by` works with window functions.

When it is not present, then the function acts like an aggregation function over the window frame definition.  That is, it returns the same value for everything in the window frame.

When it is present, then the function acts in a cumulative fashion, with the result "up to" the current row.

Of course, this is also influenced by the window frame specification.  However, your example queries do not include `rows` or `range` as well as `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

From [3.5. Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html):

> ...You can also control the order in which rows are processed by
>   window functions using ORDER BY within OVER..

This is the difference of `over (partition by user_id)` in which there is no order for processing the rows inside each group that they are divided and `over (partition by user_id order by ts)` which processes the rows after sorting them by `ts`.
This means that for each row a **new** `sum(val)` is calculated based on and up to the position of the row in the sorted rows.
Maybe it's easier to understand this for the case of `rank()` window function, so visit the link at the beginning of this answer where there is a very good example and more about this topic.

Comment: Immm, so, partition divides the entire table to the partitions, but when we use the order by with over() clause(either entire table or with partition), the given window function is calculated for each row. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Let's create one simple example to understand it properly.

We have considered one bank table with daily credit and debit.
The following query will calculate the daily balance and also total balance for a customer(`partition by` is used to divide the results for individual customers) as column names suggest with use of `SUM` analytical function with and without `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SQL> WITH BANK_TABLE (CUST_ID, DT, AMOUNT_CR_DR)
  2  AS
  3  (
  4  SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-01', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-02', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-03', -1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-04', -500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-05', 2000 FROM DUAL
  9  )
 10  SELECT DT, AMOUNT_CR_DR,
 11  SUM(AMOUNT_CR_DR) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) AS TOTAL_BALANCE_LIFE_TIME,
 12  SUM(AMOUNT_CR_DR) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID ORDER BY DT) AS TOTAL_BALANCE_TILL_DATE
 13  FROM BANK_TABLE
 14  ORDER BY CUST_ID, DT;

DT        AMOUNT_CR_DR TOTAL_BALANCE_LIFE_TIME TOTAL_BALANCE_TILL_DATE
--------- ------------ ----------------------- -----------------------
01-JAN-19         1000                    3500                    1000
02-JAN-19         2000                    3500                    3000
03-JAN-19        -1000                    3500                    2000
04-JAN-19         -500                    3500                    1500
05-JAN-19         2000                    3500                    3500
```

`Partition by` clause is used to divide rows in group and `order by` clause is to calculate the value in that order.

So for rows in order,

**For 1st row**, sum will be returned for 1st row only.

**For 2nd row**, sum will be first row plus second row.

Same way till the last row of the partition.

Cheers!!

Comment: I know this. My question is the same with your answer. But I try to find why?